# model/view is not getting refreshed after loading JSON data

Tags: ember.js

I am trying build a small search application with Ember.JS - 
Here is my code Snippet:

1. application/adapter.js

   ```
     import DS from 'ember-data';
     export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
     host: 'http://c6403:2222',
     namespace: 'server'
    });
   ```
2. searializers/results.js

   ```
   import DS from 'ember-data';
   export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
   });
   ```

tried

```
    import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
      return {
        title: payload.title,
        description: payload.description,
        type: payload.type,
        url: payload.url,
       };
      }
     });
```

3. My router/index.js

   ```
   export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function (){
    var searchText = 'searchText';

    return this.store.query('result',{ searchText } ).then(function(results) {
      alert(results);
      return results;
    });
   ```

   },

   ```
   actions:{
    submitsearch: function(searchText) {
                this.store.query('result',{ searchText } );
               this.refresh();
       }
    }
        });
   ```
4. model/results.js

   ```
     import DS from 'ember-data';
      export default  DS.Model.extend({
       title: DS.attr('string'),
        description: DS.attr('string'),
        url: DS.attr('string'),
        type: DS.attr('string'),
        searchText: DS.attr('string')
      });
   ```
5. templates/index.js:

   ```
     {{search-home  action="submitsearch"}}

      {{search-list searchlist=model}}
   ```
6. templates/components/search-list.hbs

   ```
         <ul>
       hello - this is search list page  {{ searchlist }}

          {{#each searchlist as | searchItem|}}
    <li>{{searchItem.title}}</li>
    <li>{{searchItem.description}}</li>
    <li>{{searchItem.url}}</li>
    {{/each}}
   ```

Issue: when I submit the action and trying to update the result result - store is getting the data (I could see in ember data) - but UI is not getting refreshed with new result. But I move "return this.store.query('result',{ searchText } );" code to model() block it works fine. How can I make it working from action.

Please help on this.
Note: Am using  2.11.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the model filename too.

Also adapter and so on.

Please check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e5c3e54909f79b394b2f4b911c6e49c1) out. For simplicity I omit the component and put the list in the index template.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

when I put the logic inside  model: function (){} it works fine. but I wanted to put this in action - here it does not work. can you please take a look?

actions:{
 submitsearch: function(searchText) {
...
}

Comment: @AmarnathreddyPappu I updated my twiddle, please take a look again.

Comment: This is excellent stuff. thank you very much of this help. I wanted to UP vote 1000 times for your help.

Comment: am trying to up vote but it keeps saying "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." so not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The RESTSerializer expects arrays of objects to be delivered inside a payload key matching the model name pluralized. Alternatively, you can use the JsonSerializer if you would prefer not to send a payload key.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes I did try with jsonserializer.
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({

  primaryKey: function(type){
    return 'url';
  }
});
but i am seeing the error like "typeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

Comment: thanks for the help. I have slightly modified my question. can you please take a look?